# SSMS not accepting ESRI GeoDatabase OLE DB provider as a connection

Tags: sql-server, ssms, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

I am trying to import a large dbf into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 2014 using the ESRI GeoDatabase OLE DB provider option. I am on a windows 10 machine using ArcGIS 10.4. The dbf is about 850mb (less than the 2gig limitation of SSMS 2014 Express).I am getting this error when I attempt:

[error warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xttjS.jpg)

I have had success using the flat file source option but this particular dataset gets stalled after about 10% gets imported.

The error text is this:

```
TITLE: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
------------------------------

An error occurred which the SQL Server Integration Services Wizard was not prepared to handle.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

**ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Microsoft OLE DB Service Components**)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: Is the SSIS service run? The 10% progress is just a quick jump, and then a fail.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. I am using the import wizard.